# Get data from an API and saving into a Postgresql database

Tags: php, python, postgresql

I'm starting in Python and I'm currently coding a script that gets the data from an API, processes it and save in a Postgresql database.
I'm using Django and Postgresql, both of them are dockerized.

The code is getting the data from the API and showing for me, so that part is ok. The problem now is how I save it in the database.

I used to do that in PHP with Symfony and it was something along the lines of this:

**PHP/Symfony**

```
/*Movie*/
$movie_imdb_id = 'NULL';
$movie_status = $value->isPlaying;

$movie = new Movie();
$movie->setImdbId($movie_imdb_id);
$movie->setStatus($movie_status);

$entityManager->persist($movie);
$entityManager->flush();
```

I want to make the exact same thing, but in Python.
Here it is my script so far.

**Python/Django**

```
#RestfulClient.py

import requests 
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import json
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="database", user="user", password="password", host="host", port="port")
url = "url_api"

myResponse = requests.get(url, verify = True)

if(myResponse.ok):
    jData = json.loads(myResponse.content)
    for f in jData:
      #print(json.dumps(jData, indent = 4, sort_keys = True))
      cur = conn.cursor()
      cur.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('value', 'value')")
      conn.commit()
else:
    myResponse.raise_for_status()
```

My main problem is how to **INSERT** the data that I got in the Postgres tables, since they're object.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT 1**

So, after reading the guide that @Chris post, I remade my code to something more readable

**Python 2**

```
import json
import urllib3
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="pp-db", user="root", password="root", host="db", port="5432")
cur = conn.cursor()

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = "https://api-content.ingresso.com/v0/theaters"

try:
    response = http.request('GET', url)
    data = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))

    for i in data:
        cityName = None
        uf = None

        cityName = i['cityName']
        uf = i['uf']

        cur.execute("INSERT INTO city VALUES(%s, %s)", (cityName, uf))
        conn.commit()
    cur.close()
except IOError as io:
    print("ERROR!")
```

<s>Ok, so far, so good, but when I execute the script, it returns me with a error:</s>

`psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "Rio de Janeiro"`

I'm thinking that this might be because I forgot to pass the `id`, since this table has (id, cityName, uf).
I have to manually insert the id in the table?

I've created an index as an Id key. It's working just fine.

Comment: what does f look like?

Comment: Side note: both of your code snippets are hard to read due to mixed formatting. Please pick a standard and stick with it. In PHP, `camelCase` is fairly common but there are many standards to choose from. Python has an [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that most users follow.

Comment: So, my idea here is use this `for f in jData` as an equivalent to PHP's foreach.
F is and index that will loop through all elements in jData and will insert data in Postgresql table.

Comment: You're not comparing like with like here. Your PHP code uses a framework, Symfony, in which you have clearly defined a Movie class which describes how it is supposed to be saved in the database. You can do that in Python too, with some ORM library like sqlalchemy, peewee or Django. Otherwise you'll just need to write something that translates your dictionary items to database columns.

Comment: Thanks, for the help and the guide, guys. Finally, I succeed in the code.
I think it needs better refinement, but it's ok for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some coding I've finally succeed. Here is the code that I made. 
Though, I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do that, it is working, nevertheless.

**PYTHON - WORKING**

```
import json
import urllib3
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="db", user="user", password="pass", host="host", port="port")
cur = conn.cursor()

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = "https://url"

try:
    response = http.request('GET', url)
    data = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
    index = 0 #I'm using index as an id_key

    for i in data:
        var1 = None
        var2 = None

        var1 = i['var1']
        var2 = i['var2']

        cur.execute("""
            INSERT INTO table
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s); 
            """,
            (index, var1, var2))
        conn.commit()
        index += 1 
    cur.close()
except IOError as io:
    print("ERROR!")
```

Comment: Nice work, my question is how do i create an api key, save it in postgresql database and authenticate downloads when a  client wants to get data fron the database with the api key?